# Ubuntu 14.04 how to use xset for mouse speed / sensitivity?

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I've found [Mouse sensitivity in 14.04 dissapeared](http://goo.gl/6I5fUv)

One of the answer it to use xset m 20/12 0 without any description of what it does (increase or decrease and examples).

Could anyone help me because my brand new keyboard/mouse wireless combo (Logitech mk 270 shows a too high mouse speed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want know about xset or to change speed of mouse?

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: Yes i'm try to use xset or another tool to change mouse speed on the screen (my new mouse is going too fast).

Answer (score 0):

The command you specified "xset m 20/12 0" works great for my Logitech wireless mouse. 
I have a nice Samsung wide-screen 1600x1200 1080p hd monitor. 
My speed was, however, too slow after a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit, which is a pain. 
I suggest to anybody to add it as startup item if they have wide-screen,
it works wonders.