# Mouse speed/acceleration options do not appear for my Logitech K260 combo

Tags: 14.04, mouse, logitech

The product is Logitech K260 Wireless Combo with Keyboard and Mouse: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004KSQANO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KSQANO).

The problem is, I cannot adjust the pointer speed and acceleration of the mouse in System Settings - no scroll bars appear for the mouse.

[image: This is what I mean by "no scroll bars for pointer speed"]

I am pretty sure that there was at least a "pointer speed" bar when I used another stand-along mouse on the same PC.

Now the question is:

1. How to get the bars normally, or is it even possible?
2. If I cannot get the bars anyway, how to set them up?

---

Update 3/1/2016:

I tried the `mouse-speed` package but it doesn't work for me, because in my `xinput --list --short` output, there are two devices with the same name (the keyboard and the mouse). When it runs `xinput --set-prop` it throws an exception. I am not sure if this is the reason why the mouse doesn't appear in the System Settings.

I will try to work around this by using the device ID instead, but I am not sure if the device ID is always the same every time I boot, or will it stay the same if I plug the receiver to another USB port... I guess I need some RegEx tricks here...

Answer (score 0):

relevant previous [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671314/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-use-xset-for-mouse-speed-sensitivity/778505).

```
$ man xset
$ xset m 3/2 50
```

That works for me on a big screen, where I want slow motion on small moves and fast on quick moves. It's also under a different situation: Ubuntu 16.04 with a Logitech MK270 with unifying nano-adapter plugged direct to the motherboard USB 3.0.
Good luck!